# Is the big bang (BB) correctly summarized as a sequence of symmetry-breaking events?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, symmetry-breaking, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

Please take this as a serious question from a curious yet deeply underinformed lover of this universe. This is more of a basic question concerning the overall mechanics of the transition stages from the big bang to the particles of the standard model and to its extensions.

As I understand it,the singularity was a uniformity, a perfect symmetry of everything that exists. A perfect symmetry, not only of mass, spin, color charge, chirality, electric charge, weak isospin, and hypercharge, but of location in space as well. This symmetry was so perfect, that differentiating between them is meaningless. And, if any of this is correct, the BB, began with these symmetries "slipping" in a certain order, and new classes of particle are born as those particles take on characteristics that differentiate them from each other.

For instance, since antimatter is the same as matter except with the opposite polarity, these two must have been the same class of particle before the separation of the weak and EM forces. But once that separation happened, particles that were otherwise the same because of their symmetry in mass and spin, became different classes of particles when they could now take on opposite charges.

So these symmetry-breaking events were what drove the evolution of the singularity, step-by-step, into the zoo of fundamental particles that our universe has now. And it was the order in which the symmetries broke that determined which particles interacted with which fields, and in which way each class behaved when the next subsequent symmetry broke.

Assuming this is a somewhat correct framework, can anyone elucidate for me on the order in which these events happened? Or could anyone point me to a resource for understanding this better?

edit:
I am sorry for the lack of clarity. I think maybe I am formulating my own mental picture of the BB, in response to the fact that most descriptions are too technical for my current level of growth. I shall try to be more clear.

As I understand it, when the strong nuclear force split from the electronuclear force, this was a symmetry breaking, and the particles that had existed before the break were now differentiated into particles that would be able to interact via the strong force, and those that would not be able to. Likewise, When electromagnetism split, that was another symmetry breaking, and the particle species groups that had existed before the symmetry breaking were now differentiated into those particles that would be able to interact via the electromagnetic force, and those that would not. These symmetry breaks would have had to happen for each of the characteristics (spin, chirality, color, flavour, electric charge, weak isospin, weak hypercharge, mass) that differentiate the different species of elementary particles we have today

My question: Is there any sort of consensus on which order particles gained those characteristics via the symmetry breaking of characteristics like, spin, charge, color, etc? In what order did the fundamental particles speciate from each other in their evolution from singularity to the fundamental particles of the standard model.

Comment: This sounds like your personal idea of the Big Bang. We can't comment on that, other than to say your description is not clear to us. Here is a video about more mainstream ideas. [What really happened at the Big Bang?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZdvSJyHvUU). It is pretty vague too. The real description is mathematical and precise, as far as it goes. We don't know everything. But you would need to study a while to learn it. If that is what you want, there are online resources.

Comment: [Timeline of the early universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_early_universe)

Comment: Particles and antiparticles are not unified at any energy.

Comment: You can’t summarize the Big Bang and not mention the expansion of the universe.